# Example in Chapter 1, 1.5.1, of The C Programming Language Second edittion K&R,

Tags: c, char, int, ascii, eof

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

> "This value is called EOF, for "end of file". We must declare c to be
>   a type big enough to hold EOF in addition to any possible char.
>   Therefore we use int."

Correct me if i am wrong:

- (signed) char = [-128. +127]
- unsigned char = [0, 255]
- EOF = -1

when I replace `int` with `char` in the above program it seems to work like intended , but after some research I found out that it doesn't because the variable `c` cannot store -1 aka `EOF` ( albeit using `char` ).

I run it anyway and tried to crash it, I tried to input negative number like -1 but it didn't work. I believe that is because it is interpreted like 2 different characters `-` and `1`. I tried `ÿ` which is the character corresponding to ascii value 255 according to http://ascii-code.com/, 
so for what input will the above program ( using `char` instead of `int`) crash ?

(For information, I am using a 64bit fedora Linux)

Comment: Why do you think it will crash?

Comment: `Correct me if i am wrong:` - you are wrong. Swap the `signed` and `unsigned` ranges. And as Olaf said.

Comment: `SCHAR_MIN`, the lower bound of `signed char`, is typically `-128`, not `-127`. That's for 2's-complement implementations with `CHAR_BIT==8`. Other values are possible. Plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned; it has the same range and representation as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but it's still a distinct type.

Comment: You're wrong about `char` and `unsigned char` - the possible values of `unsigned char` are 0 - 255, while (signed) `char` can hold values of -128 through 127.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If we swap the `signed` and `unsigned` ranges, these are the minimum ranges. Still not sure what the problem is for OP.

Comment: `ÿ` is not the character with the value `-1` in most encodings. This only applies to ISO 8859-1 which isn't commonly used today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been explained in other answers before, but sometimes it is harder to find the duplicate than to give the answer.

The plain `char` type can be signed or unsigned.

The function `getchar()` returns either EOF or *…obtains that character as an `unsigned
char` converted to an `int`…* (quoting the standard for `fgetc()`, but it applies to `getchar()` too).

If you have an unsigned plain `char` type, then the assignment will generate a value 0..255 which will then be promoted to `int` for the comparison with EOF, and since none of the values 0..255 is negative, the test will always fail — and the loop won't stop until you terminate the program by some other means (interrupt, reboot, …).

If you have a signed plain `char` type, then the assignment will treat both one valid character (often ÿ — U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, if you are using a single-byte code set such as ISO 8859-15) and EOF as marking EOF, so the loop may terminate prematurely on some files.

So, depending on the machine, the loop:

```
char c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    ;
```

may either be an infinite loop or it may terminate before EOF for some data files.  Neither is correct behaviour — and neither behaviour is a crash.  (The code in the question won't crash.)  Changing the type of `c` to `int` fixes both problems reliably and portably.

Note that if you are working with a UTF-8 locale, you will not generate the hex 0xFF byte; that is not a valid byte in UTF-8 (U+00FF is encoded as two bytes 0xC3 0xBF in UTF-8).

Comment: Very nice answer.  Another benefit of using `int c` involves subsequent use of `is...()` functions like `isspace()` which expects a value in the same range of `unsigned char`/`EOF`.  Code can use `isspace(c)`.  With `char c`, code should use `isspace((unsigned char)c)` to avoid UB.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it may crash that in C `char` isn't specified to be signed or unsigned. It can work well on your machine, but on it can fail on others.
And also `getchar()` function return `int` value, so you should use `int` variable to get this returning value.

Comment: Why would `char` being signed or unsigned make it crash?